# Is there a free (local) network bandwidth limiter software?

Tags: bandwidth, netlimiter

I want to be able to limit the global Download and Upload speed of my computer so that I won't be using "all" the bandwidth from my router, especially since there are other residents using it.

What software exists that allows you to limit your bandwidth?

Comment: can you add more information?  are other pcs connecting via wifi etc?  more info means a better answer.

Comment: Good Guy Apothem. +1 for being considerate of other people.

Comment: I assume the question only makes sense if you want it to work on Windows, but a confirmation of this and a specification of which version might be helpful.

Comment: Yes there will be other pcs connected via wifi/ethernet. And yes, I believe having it work for Windows 7 is sufficient. I use Fedora alongside Windows 7, and if there is a way to limit the bandwidth on Fedora as well that would be great.

Comment: Is not global bandwith, but [this article](https://www.howtogeek.com/347711/how-to-limit-any-applications-bandwidth-on-windows/) explains how to use *TMeter* to limit until 4 applications for *free*, and thus replace pay software like _NetLimiter_ or _NetBalancer_.

Answer (score 5):

There are not a lot of free bandwidth limiters for Windows as they normally require a driver to be installed, and it costs money to have them digitally signed. I used the free edition of [Net Balancer](http://seriousbit.com/netbalancer/) in the past and it did the job.

But I would see if your router has any QOS ( Quality of Service ) features as it applies to all devices and is far more effective in a shared household, especially with bit torrent traffic.

If your router does not have built in QOS features, see if it is compatible with something like [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com) which provides more options.

Answer (score 3):

I use this one:

http://bandwidthcontroller.com/trafficShaperXp.html

Comment: Apparently, *TrafficShaperXp* was discontinued, and its latest version (1.2) was released in 2007.